# Relative Element with auto-height

Tags: html, css, height, css-position

I want to auto-high my relative positioned Div and don't want to use "overflow: scroll/auto". I just want to increase my Div's height when the Childelement needs the space..

```css
#content {
    position: relative;
    background: red;
    z-index: 1;
    right: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    color: rgba(58, 58, 58,1);
    height: 560px;
}
#content p, #banner p, #content a{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 5px;
}
.table {
    position: absolute;
    left: 5%;
    right: 5%;
    display: block;
}
.tleft, .tmiddle, .tright {
    width: calc( 100% / 3 );
    float:left;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
    <div class="table">
        <div class="tleft">
            <h1><img src="images/icons/Unbenannt.png" alt="" class="nolb" />Überschrift1</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="tmiddle">
            <h1><img src="images/icons/Unbenannt.png" alt="" class="nolb" />Überschrift2</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="tright">
            <h1><img src="images/icons/Unbenannt.png" alt="" class="nolb" />Überschrift3</h1>
            <p>Das ist ein sehr langer Text umzu testen, wie das komische geteilte Div darauf reagiert und wie es danach aussieht.Das ist ein sehr langer Text umzu testen, wie das komische geteilte Div darauf reagiert und wie es danach aussieht.
            Das ist ein sehr langer Text umzu testen, wie das komische geteilte Div darauf reagiert und wie es danach aussieht.Das ist ein sehr langer Text umzu testen, wie das komische geteilte Div darauf reagiert und wie es danach aussieht.
            Das ist ein sehr langer Text umzu testen, wie das komische geteilte Div darauf reagiert und wie es danach aussieht.Das ist ein sehr langer Text umzu testen, wie das komische geteilte Div darauf reagiert und wie es danach aussieht.
            Das ist ein sehr langer Text umzu testen, wie das komische geteilte Div darauf reagiert und wie es danach aussieht.Das ist ein sehr langer Text umzu testen, wie das komische geteilte Div darauf reagiert und wie es danach aussieht.
            Das ist ein sehr langer Text umzu testen, wie das komische geteilte Div darauf reagiert und wie es danach aussieht.Das ist ein sehr langer Text umzu testen, wie das komische geteilte Div darauf reagiert und wie es danach aussieht.
            Das ist ein sehr langer Text umzu testen, wie das komische geteilte Div darauf reagiert und wie es danach aussieht.Das ist ein sehr langer Text umzu testen, wie das komische geteilte Div darauf reagiert und wie es danach aussieht.
            Das ist ein sehr langer Text umzu testen, wie das komische geteilte Div darauf reagiert und wie es danach aussieht.Das ist ein sehr langer Text umzu testen, wie das komische geteilte Div darauf reagiert und wie es danach aussieht.
            Das ist ein sehr langer Text umzu testen, wie das komische geteilte Div darauf reagiert und wie es danach aussieht.Das ist ein sehr langer Text umzu testen, wie das komische geteilte Div darauf reagiert und wie es danach aussieht.
            Das ist ein sehr langer Text umzu testen, wie das komische geteilte Div darauf reagiert und wie es danach aussieht.Das ist ein sehr langer Text umzu testen, wie das komische geteilte Div darauf reagiert und wie es danach aussieht.
            </p>
   
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I force automatically needed height for the relative positioned Div?

Best regards.

Comment: So when the div tright gets bigger, the div content should get bigger?

Comment: Not sure why you want to do this, but you can delete the height property completely and instead apply a "max-height" & equally a "min-height" to control the upper and lower growth that is allowed in the div. This way your content should auto grow between these values; that is if your inheritance in the code above "Content" is not overriding this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is another option to do this update css for .table

```
.table {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

and remove `height` of `.content`

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d5jdu9md/

```css
#content {
    position: relative;
    background: red;
    z-index: 1;
    right: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    color: rgba(58, 58, 58,1);
    
}
#content p, #banner p, #content a{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 5px;
}
.table {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.tleft, .tmiddle, .tright {
    width: calc( 100% / 3 );
    float:left;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
    <div class="table">
        <div class="tleft">
            <h1><img src="images/icons/Unbenannt.png" alt="" class="nolb" />Überschrift1</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="tmiddle">
            <h1><img src="images/icons/Unbenannt.png" alt="" class="nolb" />Überschrift2</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="tright">
            <h1><img src="images/icons/Unbenannt.png" alt="" class="nolb" />Überschrift3</h1>
            <p>Das ist ein sehr langer Text umzu testen, wie das komische geteilte Div darauf reagiert und wie es danach aussieht.Das ist ein sehr langer Text umzu testen, wie das komische geteilte Div darauf reagiert und wie es danach aussieht.
            Das ist ein sehr langer Text umzu testen, wie das komische geteilte Div darauf reagiert und wie es danach aussieht.Das ist ein sehr langer Text umzu testen, wie das komische geteilte Div darauf reagiert und wie es danach aussieht.
            Das ist ein sehr langer Text umzu testen, wie das komische geteilte Div darauf reagiert und wie es danach aussieht.Das ist ein sehr langer Text umzu testen, wie das komische geteilte Div darauf reagiert und wie es danach aussieht.
            Das ist ein sehr langer Text umzu testen, wie das komische geteilte Div darauf reagiert und wie es danach aussieht.Das ist ein sehr langer Text umzu testen, wie das komische geteilte Div darauf reagiert und wie es danach aussieht.
            Das ist ein sehr langer Text umzu testen, wie das komische geteilte Div darauf reagiert und wie es danach aussieht.Das ist ein sehr langer Text umzu testen, wie das komische geteilte Div darauf reagiert und wie es danach aussieht.
            Das ist ein sehr langer Text umzu testen, wie das komische geteilte Div darauf reagiert und wie es danach aussieht.Das ist ein sehr langer Text umzu testen, wie das komische geteilte Div darauf reagiert und wie es danach aussieht.
            Das ist ein sehr langer Text umzu testen, wie das komische geteilte Div darauf reagiert und wie es danach aussieht.Das ist ein sehr langer Text umzu testen, wie das komische geteilte Div darauf reagiert und wie es danach aussieht.
            Das ist ein sehr langer Text umzu testen, wie das komische geteilte Div darauf reagiert und wie es danach aussieht.Das ist ein sehr langer Text umzu testen, wie das komische geteilte Div darauf reagiert und wie es danach aussieht.
            Das ist ein sehr langer Text umzu testen, wie das komische geteilte Div darauf reagiert und wie es danach aussieht.Das ist ein sehr langer Text umzu testen, wie das komische geteilte Div darauf reagiert und wie es danach aussieht.
            </p>
   
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @JanikH This answer is actually the same as mine though, and also removes the `position: absolute;`.

Comment: @DarkAshelin not exactly. It changes the absolute to relative which is not "no value" at positioning.

Comment: @JanikH The result is exactly the same though. `position: relative;` has no use unless there is an `absolute` positioned child in it. Which there is not, in this case, since we removed it.

Answer (score 0):

This will not work as long as your content uses `position: absolute`, because absolute positioning means that the elements are removed from the normal flow of the DOM and your `#content` div will not be able to see the correct height of your content. See [explanation of Absolute vs Relative positioning](http://webdesign.about.com/od/advancedcss/a/aa061307.htm).

However, as far as I can see in your example, there is no reason to really use `position: absolute`, so you can remove it:

```css
#content {
    background: red;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    color: rgba(58, 58, 58,1);
}
#content p, #banner p, #content a{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 5px;
}
.table {
    margin: 0 5%;
}
.tleft, .tmiddle, .tright {
    width: calc( 100% / 3 );
    float: left;
}
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
    <div class="table">
        <div class="tleft">
            <h1><img src="images/icons/Unbenannt.png" alt="" class="nolb" />Überschrift1</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="tmiddle">
            <h1><img src="images/icons/Unbenannt.png" alt="" class="nolb" />Überschrift2</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="tright">
            <h1><img src="images/icons/Unbenannt.png" alt="" class="nolb" />Überschrift3</h1>
            <p>Das ist ein sehr langer Text umzu testen, wie das komische geteilte Div darauf reagiert und wie es danach aussieht.Das ist ein sehr langer Text umzu testen, wie das komische geteilte Div darauf reagiert und wie es danach aussieht.
            Das ist ein sehr langer Text umzu testen, wie das komische geteilte Div darauf reagiert und wie es danach aussieht.Das ist ein sehr langer Text umzu testen, wie das komische geteilte Div darauf reagiert und wie es danach aussieht.
            Das ist ein sehr langer Text umzu testen, wie das komische geteilte Div darauf reagiert und wie es danach aussieht.Das ist ein sehr langer Text umzu testen, wie das komische geteilte Div darauf reagiert und wie es danach aussieht.
            Das ist ein sehr langer Text umzu testen, wie das komische geteilte Div darauf reagiert und wie es danach aussieht.Das ist ein sehr langer Text umzu testen, wie das komische geteilte Div darauf reagiert und wie es danach aussieht.
            Das ist ein sehr langer Text umzu testen, wie das komische geteilte Div darauf reagiert und wie es danach aussieht.Das ist ein sehr langer Text umzu testen, wie das komische geteilte Div darauf reagiert und wie es danach aussieht.
            Das ist ein sehr langer Text umzu testen, wie das komische geteilte Div darauf reagiert und wie es danach aussieht.Das ist ein sehr langer Text umzu testen, wie das komische geteilte Div darauf reagiert und wie es danach aussieht.
            Das ist ein sehr langer Text umzu testen, wie das komische geteilte Div darauf reagiert und wie es danach aussieht.Das ist ein sehr langer Text umzu testen, wie das komische geteilte Div darauf reagiert und wie es danach aussieht.
            Das ist ein sehr langer Text umzu testen, wie das komische geteilte Div darauf reagiert und wie es danach aussieht.Das ist ein sehr langer Text umzu testen, wie das komische geteilte Div darauf reagiert und wie es danach aussieht.
            Das ist ein sehr langer Text umzu testen, wie das komische geteilte Div darauf reagiert und wie es danach aussieht.Das ist ein sehr langer Text umzu testen, wie das komische geteilte Div darauf reagiert und wie es danach aussieht.
            </p>
   
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Do note that I added a `clear: both` div at the end to [clear your floats](https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/) so your parent element has the correct height.

Comment: Hey,
thanks but it's just a snippet. In my complete website, the absolute position. otherwise it looks teribble

Comment: @JanikH What are you using the absolute position for? I recon it can be solved without it as well. I believe you are using `position: absolute` in the wrong way.